# CDPATH functionality in Powershell?

Tags: bash, powershell

Has anyone implemented the equivalent behavior of [bash's 'cdpath'](http://www.caliban.org/bash/#bashtips) in Powershell?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did not know about CDPATH before. Good to know. I whipped up the below for Powershell:

```
function cd2 {
    param($path)
    if(-not $path){return;}

    if((test-path $path) -or (-not $env:CDPATH)){
        Set-Location $path
        return
    }
    $cdpath = $env:CDPATH.split(";") | % { $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($_) }
    $npath = ""
    foreach($p in $cdpath){
        $tpath = join-path $p $path
        if(test-path $tpath){$npath = $tpath; break;}
    }
    if($npath){
        #write-host -fore yellow "Using CDPATH"
        Set-Location $npath
        return
    }

    set-location $path

}
```

It will not be perfect, but works in the expected way. You can extend it I guess. Add it to your profile. If needed, also add an alias like so:

```
set-alias -Name cd -value cd2 -Option AllScope
```