# Directory Bookmarks in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

One of my favorite Bash tips involves creating aliases for marking and returning to directories as described here: http://www.huyng.com/archives/quick-bash-tip-directory-bookmarks/492/.

In Bash, it looks like this:

```
alias m1='alias g1="cd `pwd`"'
```

Is it possible to create a similar function in powershell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the following to the `$profile`:

```
$marks = @{};

$marksPath = Join-Path (split-path -parent $profile) .bookmarks

if(test-path $marksPath){
import-csv $marksPath | %{$marks[$_.key]=$_.value}
}

function m($number){
$marks["$number"] = (pwd).path
}

function g($number){
cd $marks["$number"]
}

function mdump{
$marks.getenumerator() | export-csv $marksPath -notype
}

function lma{
$marks
}
```

I didn't like the way of defining an alias for each like `m1`, `m2` and so on. Instead you will be doing `m 1` and `g 1` etc.

You can also add the line

```
Register-EngineEvent PowerShell.Exiting –Action { mdump } | out-null
```

so that it will do `mdump` when you exit the Powershell session. Unfortunately, doesn't work if you close the console window, but when you type exit.

PS: Also have a look at CDPATH: [CDPATH functionality in Powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7236594/cdpath-functionality-in-powershell/7237070#7237070)

Answer (score 8):

This project works very well: http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2016/05/06/powershell-location-bookmark-for-easy-and-faster-navigation/

Install:

```
Install-Module -Name PSBookmark
```

Use:

```
#This will save $PWD as scripts
save scripts 

#This will save C:\Documents as docs
save docs C:\Documents

#You don't have to type the alias name.
#Instead, you can just tab complete. This function uses dynamic parameters.
goto docs
```

Answer (score 4):

Long-time ago I created some module with such functionality. Now I think it quite stable to add a link to the  [Powershell gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Bookmarks/)   and the [GitHub project](https://github.com/stadub/PowershellScripts/tree/master/Bookmarks) :)

Install module function:

```
Install-Module -Name Bookmarks
```

Basic usage:

```
$pwd |  ba -Name "BookmarkName" #add
bo  BookmarkName #open
br BookmarkName #remove
bl #list
```

Entire functions list is listed on the [GitHub project](https://github.com/stadub/PowershellScripts/tree/master/Bookmarks)  page

Answer (score 2):

I use this trick:

im my $profile I wrote function like this:

```
 function win { Set-Location c:\windows}

 $ProfileDir = $PROFILE.Substring(0 , $PROFILE.LastIndexOf("\")+1)
 function pro { Set-Location $profiledir}
```

and so on...